# Find $DX$ in a triangle with known sides

Tags: geometry

In the triangle $ABC$ we have $AB=15$, $BC=24$, and $CA=18$. $AD$ is the bisector of $A$, and $CD \perp AD$. Also, $X$ is the middle of $BC$. We have to find the value of $DX$.

[image]

Using the bisector theorem, I've found that $EC=\frac{144}{11}$ and $EB=\frac{120}{11}$. From here, I don't know how to continue it. Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $\overline{BX} = \overline{XC}$. Also, let $C'$ be the intersection of $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$. Then clearly $\overline{C'D} = \overline{DC}$. So $\overline{DX} /\!/ \ \overline{AB}$.

We know that $\overline{BE}:\overline{EC} = 5:6$. Together with $\overline{BX} = \overline{XC}$, we see that $\overline{BE}:\overline{EX} = 10:1$. Hence $\overline{AB}:\overline{DX} = 10:1$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I will use a picture of **Hw Chu**. Since $AC' = AC$ we have $BC'=3$ and since $DX$ is middle line in triangle $CBC'$ parallel to $BC'$ we have $DX = 3/2$.

Comment: Nice shortcut! :)